# Replace text at top-level of node without breaking formatting of children

Tags: javascript

If I have the following html code:

```
<div id="element">
Qwerty Foo Bar 
<span style="color: red;">This text should/will never be changed by the script.</span>
</div>
```

And I want to change "Foo" to "baz", I can do the following:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
element.innerText = element.innerText.replace('Foo', 'baz');
```

However this will destroy the formatting of the red text.

How can you do this?

I don't need cross-browser support, only support for chrome and I don't want to use a js framework. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLzJD/3/

Comment: You can't reuse the same `ID` attribute as you have in the jsfiddle demo.

Comment: @Jared: I think you missed the point. The second line should stay red.

Comment: @Felix - Yes, I did miss that (but I am right the OP only cares about Chrome).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate over the children and only modify text nodes:

```
var children = element.childNodes,
    child;

for(var i = children.length; i--; ) {
    child = children[i];
    if(child.nodeType === 3) {
        child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace('Foo', 'baz');
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cLzJD/1/)

**Notes:**

- If you want to replace all occurrences of `Foo`, you have to use a regular expression: `replace(/Foo/g, 'baz')`.
- The advantage of this approach is that event handlers bound through JavaScript will stay intact. If you don't need this, `innerHTML` will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Felix Kling's solution is the best approach, in your special case you could use  `.innerHTML` instead of `.innerText`.

```
element.innerHtml = element.innerHtml.replace('Foo', 'baz');
```

`.replace()` will only replace the first occurrence, so if you're sure there is no HTML content before your text, you can use it. Otherwise it could break your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the formatting because you're using innerText (which will return the contents with all the HTML stripped out). Just use innerHTML instead: http://jsfiddle.net/cLzJD/4/ (I've also changed the ids to be unique).